# How do I get the 6th Datacron on Dromund Kaas

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In Beta, there were only 5 Datacrons on Dromund Kaas.

However, when the game launched, the planetary information was updated to say there were six Datacrons.

Where is the last one?

The five I've located are:

1. In the spaceport, in Docking Bay D-61.
2. South-west of the Spaceport.
3. Above the waterfall in the south-west corner of the Malignant Bog Heroic area.
4. In the mountains north-west of Lord Grathan's Estate.
5. On a rock in Dark Temple Approach near the Mercenary Landing Site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't the Codex track lore entries? You get a sixth lore entry by entering the Assembly Chamber near the Dark Temple.

I'm pretty sure there are only 3 on starter planet, 5 on every subsequent planet.

Comment: The Codex tracks a number of things for planets.  One of them is "Achievement: Datacrons".  I currently have 5/6 for Dromund Kaas.

Comment: @Powerlord I'm pretty sure that missing entry is the chamber. Take a look: http://www.swtor-spy.com/codex/dromund-kaas-codex-entries/32/

Comment: Turns out, you're right.  The Datacrons entry is counting the Assembly Chamber entry.